# SQL Server ContainsTable not finding partial matches

Tags: sql-server-2005, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to use ContainsTable to return a ranked list of results.

I have it working fine when it finds a whole word match but its doesnt seem to work for partial words. For example if I search for 'acq' it wont find 'Acquisitions'. I really need it to work with partial matches for it to be useful. Using "Like" is not an option as the results need to be weighted.

```
SELECT
    TitleRanks.RANK,
    CourseId,
    CourseTitle         
FROM
    TBL_LMS_CLIENT_COURSES as Courses
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Courses,CourseTitle,'acq') AS TitleRanks 
        ON Courses.CourseId = TitleRanks.[key]
```

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the scenario prevent you using a prefix term in the contains clause?

```
 INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Courses,CourseTitle,'"acq*"')
```

Comment: Thats one option, I would rather a solution that looked at each word and did a contains but it sounds like thats outside the scope of freetext and would be cumbersome to implement.